# How to pass Generic parameters to hadoop jar

Tags: java, hadoop

I am passing parameters to hadoop jar as below:

```
hadoop  jar C:\Pointerfile.jar main.com.asos.recommendations.Pointerfile -D Signal=Signaltest -D ProductData=ProductData -D CustomerSegment=CustomerSegment -D CustomerCategory=CustomerCategory -D P2PSimilarity=P2PSimilarity -D ProductCategory=ProductCategory/test -D ProductSegment=ProductSegment/test  -D Customer=Customer -D ProductDataCN=ProductDatab -D CustomerSegmentCN=CustomerSegmentb -D CustomerCategoryCN=CustomerCategoryb -D P2PSimilarityCN=P2PSimilarityb -D ProductCategoryCN=ProductCategoryb -D ProductSegmentCN=ProductSegmentb -D SignalCN=Signalb -D CustomerCN=Customerb -D SAN=SAN -D version=v0.1
```

In java code I am trying to access those parameters:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();        
System.out.println("parameters are" + conf.get("Signal"));
```

but it returns null.

I have also tried by removing space:
 -DSignal=Signal and "-DSignal=Signal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this kind of class :

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class MyClass extends Configured implements Tool {

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = getConf();
        System.out.println("parameters are" + conf.get("Signal"));

        // Some code ...

        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new MyClass(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

In this class, getConf() will be filled with the parameters.
For call, don't use spaces nor quotes :

```
hadoop  jar C:\Pointerfile.jar main.com.asos.recommendations.Pointerfile -DSignal=Signaltest -DProductData=ProductData -DCustomerSegment=CustomerSegment -DCustomerCategory=CustomerCategory -DP2PSimilarity=P2PSimilarity -DProductCategory=ProductCategory/test -DProductSegment=ProductSegment/test  -DCustomer=Customer -DProductDataCN=ProductDatab -DCustomerSegmentCN=CustomerSegmentb -DCustomerCategoryCN=CustomerCategoryb -DP2PSimilarityCN=P2PSimilarityb -DProductCategoryCN=ProductCategoryb -DProductSegmentCN=ProductSegmentb -DSignalCN=Signalb -DCustomerCN=Customerb -DSAN=SAN -Dversion=v0.1
```

Comment: Thank you Simon ! It worked. But if I mention the class name between jar C:\Pointerfile.jar and -D parameters it is not working, the parameters are null. If I remove the class name it is fine. Could you help me with that issue

Comment: Humm, pretty strange. I have no idea why this happens. The command seems good : [http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html#jar]. You can cheat and delete the second args before calling the `ToolRunner.run()`, this may work.

Comment: Smart idea. It worked. But I couldn't get the root cause. As we are  submitting the jar from Azure ADF we need to pass the class name. As it is working for now, no blockers for our release :-) . Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does the way I generate the jar matters ?? I have META_INF file in jar generated, which contains mentions the main class. So is that not expecting the class name in the jar command